# how does one fix a class not found error in jboss 7.4?

Tags: jboss, migration

all,

I am trying to migrate an application from 7.1 to 7.4, and I ran into an error, I am not sure about. I have the old installation running, and I tried to use the migration tool, which promptly crashed saying the migration was unsupported.

So, I am trying to do a manual migration. I copied the node config from the old setup to the 7.4 installation and started the server. Jboss comes up and I can access the admin portal, but the app is unreachable. I get two errors... I copied the modules directory from the older server to the new server as the that both in 7.x version, however, it is still complaining...

It sounds like a missing module, from the error, but copying the folder should have fixed that no? Any Ideas, what it is that I am missing?

Console log....

```
17:26:10,580 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.7.Final-redhat-00001
17:26:11,641 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1
17:26:11,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.1.6.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.21.Final-redhat-00001) starting
17:26:11,788 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Configured system properties:
    [Standalone] = 
... 
17:26:11,789 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) VM Arguments: -D[Standalone] -verbose:gc -Xloggc:node1/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Djdk.serialFilter=maxbytes=10485760;maxdepth=128;maxarray=100000;maxrefs=300000 -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=0000 -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full.xml -Dapp.server.hosting=ALN -Dapp.server.profile=TEST -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=node1/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:node1/configuration/logging.properties 
17:26:14,320 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
17:26:14,383 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.12.Final-redhat-00001
17:26:14,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
17:26:17,216 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
17:26:17,276 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO version 3.5.6.Final-redhat-00001
17:26:17,283 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.6.Final-redhat-00001
17:26:17,389 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
17:26:17,411 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
17:26:17,420 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
17:26:17,448 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [mojarra-2.1.28, main]
17:26:17,459 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
17:26:17,508 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.SP11-redhat-00001 starting
17:26:17,509 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.0.26.Final-redhat-1
17:26:17,520 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
17:26:17,523 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
17:26:17,580 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-3
17:26:17,633 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 4 core threads with 32 task threads based on your 2 available processors
17:26:17,659 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.8.Final-redhat-1
17:26:17,706 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
17:26:17,722 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:26:17,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001)
17:26:17,980 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver (version 12.2)
17:26:18,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
17:26:18,071 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = oracle
17:26:18,071 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
17:26:18,337 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
17:26:18,343 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 8 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
17:26:18,527 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/jboss-eap-7.4/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
17:26:18,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) IJ020018: Enabling <validate-on-match> for java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/appRODS
17:26:18,628 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
17:26:18,631 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
17:26:18,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
17:26:18,755 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8380
17:26:18,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0098: Bound non-transactional data source: java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/appRODS
17:26:18,861 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
17:26:19,007 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYPAT0050: JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: jboss-eap-7.4.14.CP, one-off patches include: none
17:26:19,025 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDM0111: Keystore node1/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
17:26:19,036 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "app-webservice.war" (runtime-name: "app-webservice.war")
17:26:19,040 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "app-web-7.0.0.war" (runtime-name: "app-web-7.0.0.war")
17:26:19,061 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
17:26:19,073 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory node1/deployments
17:26:19,428 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8743
17:26:19,459 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=node1/data/activemq/journal,bindingsDirectory=node1/data/activemq/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=node1/data/activemq/largemessages,pagingDirectory=node1/data/activemq/paging)
17:26:19,596 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ws.config: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ws.config: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1978) [jboss-msc-1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_402]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_402]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [rt.jar:1.8.0_402]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wss4j/common/crypto/WSProviderConfig
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.config.CXFStackConfig.<init>(CXFStackConfigFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.config.CXFStackConfigFactory.getStackConfig(CXFStackConfigFactory.java:47)
    at org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig.setStackConfig(AbstractServerConfig.java:361)
    at org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig.create(AbstractServerConfig.java:339)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.config.ServerConfigImpl.create(ServerConfigImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.service.ServerConfigService.start(ServerConfigService.java:70)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032) [jboss-msc-1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955) [jboss-msc-1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.WSProviderConfig from [Module "org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-server" from local module loader @357246de (finder: local module finder @28f67ac7 (roots: /jboss-eap-7.4/modules,/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/jbeap16502,/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.1.6.CP,/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    ... 11 more

17:26:19,630 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
17:26:19,766 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
17:26:19,767 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
17:26:20,957 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
17:26:20,958 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
17:26:20,958 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
17:26:20,958 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
17:26:21,416 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221007: Server is now live
17:26:21,416 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 1.5.5.015-redhat-00001 [default, nodeID=7e2930c0-323b-11eb-b144-00505684da8d] 
17:26:21,463 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221003: Deploying queue jms.queue.DLQ
17:26:21,826 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
17:26:21,858 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) AMQ122005: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected for "http-connector" connector. Switching to "localhost". If this new address is incorrect please manually configure the connector to use the proper one.
17:26:21,859 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
17:26:21,872 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
17:26:21,860 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) AMQ221003: Deploying queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
17:26:22,546 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-2) Resource adaptor started
17:26:22,547 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-2) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
17:26:22,549 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
17:26:22,549 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
17:26:38,371 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.ws.config" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wss4j/common/crypto/WSProviderConfig
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.WSProviderConfig from [Module \"org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-server\" from local module loader @357246de (finder: local module finder @28f67ac7 (roots: /jboss-eap-7.4/modules,/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/jbeap16502,/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.1.6.CP,/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base))]"}}
17:26:38,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "app-web-7.0.0.war" (runtime-name : "app-web-7.0.0.war")
17:26:38,444 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "app-webservice.war" (runtime-name : "app-webservice.war")
17:26:38,476 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.ws.config: Failed to start service

17:26:38,831 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
17:26:38,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:0001/management
17:26:38,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:0001
17:26:38,866 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: JBoss EAP 7.1.6.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.21.Final-redhat-00001) started (with errors) in 28702ms - Started 343 of 608 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 364 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Ta,

X

Comment: /jboss-eap-7.4/modules,/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/jbeap16502,/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.1.6.CP it looks like you have applied a 7.1.6 CP on 7.4 which won't work

Comment: HI, ehsavoie, yes, it was copied across when I dumped the modules, it was looking for the log4j 7.1.6jar file for some reason, but could not find it. There is also, overlays for 7.2 and a few others....  I thought those were just patches that were applied to the previous installation.

Comment: You should start from a fresh installation. Not sure about the log4j 7.1.6.jar and why you need it as you should either rely on jboss modules or use your own in which case they should be in a 'separate' tree